# Can we used File System Events in Sandbox Mac App?

Tags: macos, filesystems, sandbox, appstore-sandbox, fsevents

I want to monitor any directory using [File System Events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/file_system_events?language=objc) in sandbox application.

Please any one confirm [File System Events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/file_system_events?language=objc) used in sandbox application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use them. To start the stream and to read a directory you'll need to ask user for permission using a NSOpenPanel.

Comment: Thanks for reply..
I already have user home folder permission, but I can't get any monitor  event from downloads folder

Comment: You need either add code to your question or ask a new one. Also it would motivate me and others to answer when you accept answers to your previous questions.